# Communication between components Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, components

I'm working with Angular 10 and Angular Material (I'm a beginner with this framework). Right now I have a table with some data to show to the user. When the user clicks a button a modal must show to him. I already have the modal and it appears when the user clicks the button, but the modal must fill with the data of each row of the table (each row contains different data). I'm using mat-dialog to show the modal to the user.
Here an example of the array that contains the data of the table:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {invoice: 1, category: 'Hydrogen', description: 'Hi!', startDate: 'H', status: '1', see: ''},
  {invoice: 2, category: 'Helium', description: 'Hi!', startDate: 'He', status: '1', see: ''},
  {invoice: 3, category: 'Lithium', description: 'Hi!', startDate: 'Li', status: '1', see: ''},
  {invoice: 4, category: 'Beryllium', description: 'Hi!', startDate: 'Be', status: '1', see: ''},
  {invoice: 5, category: 'Boron', description: 'Hi!', startDate: 'B', status: '1', see: ''},
  {invoice: 6, category: 'Carbon', description: 'Hi!', startDate: 'C', status: '1', see: ''},
  {invoice: 7, category: 'Nitrogen', description: 'Hi!', startDate: 'N', status: '1', see: ''},
  {invoice: 8, category: 'Oxygen', description: 'Hi!', startDate: 'O', status: '1', see: ''},
  {invoice: 9, category: 'Fluorine', description: 'Hi!', startDate: 'F', status: '1', see: ''},
  {invoice: 10, category: 'Neon', description: 'Hi!', startDate: 'Ne', status: '1', see: ''},
];
```

Here the view of the table:
[image]

When the user Clicks the last icon the Dialog appears and it must contain what the row contains. The problem is that I'm not able to communicate my data-table component with my dialog-example component.
Is there some way to pass the data of my table component to my dialog component?

Thank You very much for your help!

PS. If you need more context please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this like as follows. First you need to create your `DialogComponent`

`TableDialogComponent.ts`

```
export class TableDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TableDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: any
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

`TableDialogComponent.html`

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{ dialogData.title }}</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
  <div>
      {{dialogData.message}} // here you can play with your data that you bind to the message property
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Done</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Then in your user table row button click you can pass your element to `showDialog(element)` method. Where `element` is the table data you bind

```
showDataDialog(data: any): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TableDialogComponent, {
      width: '350px',
      data: {
        title: `Table Title`,
        message: data, // Here you can send anything for your modal component
      },
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {});
}
```

Comment: Hi! At first, thanks for your answer.
I'm trying just like data but I'm not able to show the data. The data in showDataDialog shows undefined. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: nvm, I already saw what is causing that undefined. I already accepted your answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using services. Services are singletons so there is only 1 copy of the class (and the data) shared across all components, and I think could be used in this situation.

Basically you would define or somehow set your ELEMENT_DATA into a service.

so you have a MyService.ts with that variable in that file.

And then you would inject your service into both components the parent component and the modal component (this is done via Providers on the components config).

example

```
myService : MyService
```

Now both components can access

```
myService.ELEMENT_DATA
```

and you can ensure you're always referencing the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to the dialog and use @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) to get passed data.

```
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

dialogConfig.data = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Angular For Beginners'
};
```

for communication between components use of Subject or BehaviourSubject in service. You can next and subscribe data.